# Differential Equation (Non linear to linear differential equation)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the substitution $u=\frac{1}{y}$ transform the non-linear differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=y^2\ln (x)$$ into the linear differential equation $$\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{u}{x}=-\ln (x)$$. Solve this linear differential equation, and hence obtain $y$ in terms of $x$, given that $y=\frac{1}{2}$ when $x=1$

My attempt,

$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=y^2\ln (x)$

$\frac{-\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}-\frac{1}{xy}=-\ln (x)$

Let $u=\frac{1}{y}$ $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{-\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}$

$\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=-\ln (x)$

$e^{\int -\frac{1}{x}dx}=\frac{1}{x}$

$\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{x}-\frac{u}{x^2}=-\frac{\ln (x)}{x}$

$\frac{\frac{du}{dx}}{x}+\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x})u=-\frac{\ln (x)}{x}$

$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{u}{x})=\frac{-\ln (x)}{x}$

$\int \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{u}{x})dx=\int \frac{-\ln (x)}{x}dx$

$\frac{u}{x}=-\frac{1}{2}\ln ^2(x)+c_1$

$u=x(-\frac{1}{2}\ln ^2(x)+c_1)$

$y=\frac{1}{u}=\frac{2}{-x\ln ^2(x)+2c_1x}$

$y=\frac{2}{-x\ln ^2(x)+c_1x}$

When $x=1$, $y=\frac{1}{2}$
I got $c_1=4$

Therefore, $y=\frac{2}{-x\ln ^2(x)+4x}$

Is this working right? Is there another method to solve this question?

Comment: It is correct. I can't find another method easily.

Comment: you made a typo after the $u$ sub. Also you can check the result by plugging it back in.

Answer (score 0):

$$
y' + \frac{y}{x} = y^2\ln x
$$
lets multiply by $x$ we find
$$
xy' + y = \frac{d}{dx}(xy) = xy^2\ln x
$$
let $u = xy$ we find
$$
u' = \frac{u^2}{x}\ln x
$$
thus we find
$$
\int\frac{du}{u^2} = \int \frac{\ln x}{x}dx = \int \ln x\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln x dx = \int \dfrac{d}{dx}\frac{(\ln x)^2}{2}dx = \frac{(\ln x)^2}{2} +C
$$
so we find
$$
-\frac{1}{u} = \frac{(\ln x)^2}{2} + C
$$
so we get
$$
u = \frac{-1}{ \frac{(\ln x)^2}{2} + C} 
$$
thus we lead to
$$
y = \frac{1}{x}\frac{-1}{ \frac{(\ln x)^2}{2} + C} = \frac{2}{-x\ln^2x -2Cx}
$$
Is this easier, I can not say.